# Change source .css file in react with an event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have App.css file and Appcustom.css. These files have different themes. I would like to change the source from App.css to Appcustom.css on a **button click**.

`import './App.css';`

to

`import './Appcustom.css';`.

How can this be achieved or is there any other standard way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using any UI libraries?

Comment: static imports are done on file-loads, not on component re-renders. So, changing the imports are not the standard way of loading styles. instead, you can import both files and then apply different themes and styles conditionally (which is usually done by using different classNames).

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating the file path like this

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class MainPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {stylePath: 'style1.css'};
    }

    handleButtonClick(){
        this.setState({stylePath: 'style2.css'});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={this.state.stylePath} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Click to update stylesheet</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

But I'd recommend exploring CSS in JS solutions for something like this. [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.9.1-alpha.2).